# Can someone explain how does the work flow of this tk project works? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I was taking a bootcamp and we're creating this POMODORO TIMER, but as you can see in the code, there are parts like this one:
[image]

Where we use the recursive function, and I don't know at what moment the line with the -> title_label.config...... run because we're passing and passing through this count_down function.

And on the other hand, also in this part [image]
If `start_timer()` is called and the `start_timer()` function itself calls the `count_down()` function how does it ever come back to the code in the box?

It works, but I don't know why! I would appreciate your help in explaining how this works, please!

```
from tkinter import *
import math

# ---------------------------- CONSTANTS ------------------------------- #
PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
WORK_MIN = 25
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 1
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20
reps = 0
timer = None


# ---------------------------- TIMER RESET ------------------------------- #
def reset_timer():
    window.after_cancel(timer)
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text="00:00")
    title_label.config(text="Timer")
    check_marks.config(text="")
    global reps
    reps = 0


# ---------------------------- TIMER MECHANISM ------------------------------- # 
def start_timer():
    global reps
    reps += 1
    work_sec = WORK_MIN * 60
    short_break_sec = SHORT_BREAK_MIN * 60
    long_break_sec = LONG_BREAK_MIN * 60

    if reps % 8 == 0:
        count_down(long_break_sec)
        title_label.config(text="Break", fg=RED)
    elif reps % 2 == 0:
        count_down(short_break_sec)
        title_label.config(text="Break", fg=PINK)
    else:
        count_down(work_sec)
        title_label.config(text="Work", fg=GREEN)


# ---------------------------- COUNTDOWN MECHANISM ------------------------------- #
def count_down(count):
    global timer

    count_min = math.floor(count / 60) # 1
    count_sec = count % 60 # 0
    if count_sec < 10:
        count_sec = f"0{count_sec}"

    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{count_min}:{count_sec}") # 1:00
    if count > 0:
        timer = window.after(1000, count_down, count - 1)
    else:
        start_timer()
        marks = ""
        work_sessions = math.floor(reps/2)
        for _ in range(work_sessions):
            marks += "✔"
        check_marks.config(text=marks)


# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #

window = Tk()
window.title("Pomodoro")
window.config(padx=100, pady=50, bg=YELLOW)

title_label = Label(text="Timer", fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW, font=(FONT_NAME, 50))
title_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
tomato_img = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 112, image=tomato_img)
timer_text = canvas.create_text(100, 130, text="00:00", fill="white", font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
canvas.grid(row=1, column=1)

start_button = Button(text="Start", highlightbackground=YELLOW, command=start_timer)
start_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

reset_button = Button(text="Reset", highlightbackground=YELLOW, command=reset_timer)
reset_button.grid(row=2, column=2)

check_marks = Label(fg=GREEN, bg=YELLOW)
check_marks.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `window.after()` doesn't wait for the timeout to complete, it returns immediately, and then `count_down()` returns to `start_timer()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please don't post pictures of code. Rather use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to get nicely formatted code as text.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awkward design.

`start_timer` always calls `count_down` with a non-zero number of seconds.  `count_down` then sets the text in the `timer_text`.  Since `count` is non-zero, it calls `window.after` and returns.  That allows `start_timer` to return.

`window.after` is going to call `count_down` a second later.  `count` will still be non-zero, so it calls `window.after` again, effectively giving it a 1-per-second callback.  When `count` goes to zero, THEN it will call `start_timer`, which starts a new count down.

The key is that `count_down` always returns when count > 0, and when `start_timer` calls it, count is always > 0.  Thus, everything works out.